# how to make value of select option equal to the name of select option

Tags: reactjs, axios, html-select

[image]

````
```
````

### **why id of select option not equal to select option name**
**why id of select option not equal to select option name**

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios
    .get("http://localhost:5000/Client")
    .then((response) => {
    this.setState({ client: [...response.data] });
    console.log(response.data);
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
 axios
   .get("http://localhost:5000/articles")
   .then((response) => {
    this.setState({ codeArticleList: [...response.data] });
    console.log(response.data);
    })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  console.log(this.state.codeArticleList);
}
 handleChangeCdArt = (e) => {
this.setState({
  codeArtValue: e.target.value,
  });
  console.log(this.state.codeArtValue);
  };
```

```
**why id of select option not equal to select option name**
```

Comment: add code in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) . it's great.